# C# websocket server - doesn't capture Sec-WebSocket-Key

Tags: c#, websocket

My server works to the point that I'm able to publish a basic website.  Where it fails is that it doesn't capture the Sec-WebSocket-Key header which is needed for the websocket.  I'm on a windows server 2012 operating system.  Looking for pointers on how to solve this issue!

Console Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kro4.png)

```
The server:

using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebServerTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\html scripts\\web_client4.html";
            string content_data = File.ReadAllText(path);

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\mypfx.pfx", "1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("156.96.119.19"), 443);
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("server running:  " + server.LocalEndpoint.ToString());


            while (true)
            {
                Socket socket = server.AcceptSocket();
               


                int count = 0;
                
                   
                string data = content_data;
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToCharArray(), 0, (int)data.Length);

                SslStream stream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(socket, true));
                stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, true);

                new Thread(() => {

                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int i = stream.ReadByte();
                            if (i == -1) break;
                            char c = (char)i;
                            if (c == '\n')
                            {
                                if (count == 1)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.Write(c);
                                }
                                count = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.Write(c);
                                count++;
                            }

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }


                    Console.WriteLine("end of stream reached");

                    if (socket.Connected == true)
                    {
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
                        stream.Close();
                    }

                }).Start();
                    
                





            }
        }

    }

}


The client:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <br><br>
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        
        document.writeln("testing websockets:  the current date-time is, ");
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        document.writeln(date + "  " + time);
        
        var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://156.96.119.19:443");
        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```